# Getting Started with Unreal Engine 4 - Cannot find cl.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

So I recently started using UE4, and am trying to make a C++ game. I have Visual Studio 2017, and am aware of the location of cl.exe (I actually have 4 of them):

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\Hostx[64 or 86]\x[64 or 86]\cl.exe
```

So I go into regedit to change the location to

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\Hostx64\x64
```

However, Unreal Engine, automatically adds `/bin/` to the file path specified.

So my question is the following: which of the 4 cl.exes do I use for Unreal Engine, and is there a way to stop Unreal from adding `\bin\` to the path, or should I rename the folder (probably a bad idea).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider setting it to *D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503* and letting UE4 add the bin and proper platform based on the target? Don't know if that works (which is why this is a comment and not an answer), but it would have been my first attempt.

Comment: @KenWhite In that folder, there is `/bin/` and `/Hostx64` and `/Hostx86` and each of those have two subfolders `/x64` and `/x86`

Comment: So? Did you try what I suggested? It seems to me that UE4 would make that adjustment if it's altering the path to add a folder.

Comment: @KenWhite no, it doesn't work.  It looks for `D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\cl.exe`

Comment: Sounds like a bug in UE4 then. Not sure what we can do about it here. Are you sure it's been updated to work with VS 2017?

Comment: When I started using UE, I never had to deal with cl.exe. Why are you concerning yourself with this in the first place?

Comment: @ZiadHamdieh UE4 requires me to have cl.exe before I can do anything

Comment: Did you install all the prerequisites? I think VS2017 still needs VS2015 prerequisites.